# Getting value from JTable as Integer?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I don't get it; I'm using the `DefaultTableModel`, and my attempt was this to get the value in a tabel as an `int`:

```
Integer.parseInt( tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1) );
```

Eclipse is saying there is a cast needed from `Object` to `String`, so eclipse makes that:

```
Integer.parseInt( (String) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1) );
```

At runtime, the program crashes because it is not possible to cast "int to string". Why? I expected "object -> string -> int".

Comment: you forgot `.toString()`

Comment: Why would you first convert the Integer to String and then back to Integer?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows how you add data to your `DefaultTableModel` and a complete stack trace of any error you encounter. Otherwise respondents can only  speculate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use:

```
Integer.parseInt( tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1).toString() );
```

Just set string representation of the object by using `toString()`.

Comment: Stupid... I thought too much in c/c++, of course my cast did not work.

Answer (score 3):

The value you are getting by `tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1)` already is an `Integer`. Just cast it appropriately: `Integer value = (Integer) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1);`
(or `int` if you want to use the primitive type).

Comment: No, `tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1)` returns an Object by default, per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).

Comment: In OPs case it is an Integer. Otherwise he would not get the ClassCastException he describes.