# Java error: 'java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer'

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

When I run the following code I get an error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

This is my code:

```
try{
       int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
       String myUrl = "jdbc:mySql://localhost:3306/hospital"; 
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl,"root","");
       con.setAutoCommit(false);


            String query = "Insert into `test and treatment_has_admission`(`Test and Treatment_id`,`Admission_a_id`,`Test_Result`,`Treatment_Result`,`Date`)"+" values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            for(int row=0; row<rows; row++){
                int TestTreatmentID = (int) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
                String test_result = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
                String treatment_result = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);
                String Date = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 4);
                pst.setInt(1,TestTreatmentID);
                pst.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()));
                pst.setString(3, test_result);
                pst.setString(4, treatment_result);
                pst.setString(5, Date);

                pst.addBatch();
            }
            pst.executeBatch();
            con.commit();
            con.close();
        }


    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

> Error:    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.Integer

Why am I receiving such an error? Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: It seems your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921446/getting-value-from-jtable-as-integer

Comment: That is so **weird**!!!! 5 lines down, you know how to use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert a `String` to an `int`. How come you don't know that 5 lines before?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String can't cast into Integer. Use this

```
 int TestTreatmentID = Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1));
```

**EDIT**

```
 String string= jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
 int TestTreatmentID = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Comment: `jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1)` returns an Object.

Comment: @JoeC my mistake, edited

Comment: thanks alot.  this is a good help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got problem at line

```
int TestTreatmentID = (int) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
```

Let's use `Integer.parseInt` instead

```
Integer TestTreatmentID = Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
```

Comment: Thanks alot..that  helped

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply typecast integers like this

```
int TestTreatmentID = (int) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
```

Instead, parse this string to get proper integer value

```
int TestTreatmentID = Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the value returned from method to Int using

```
Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1));
```